# review of [space] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Another tag for collective review:

[space](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space) has [four links](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space).

Two are recent, and very similar to each other referencing space from the Mars probe.
The third has space as the 5th tag, and it's discussing searching / branching.
The last is in reference to outer space techniques.

My vote is to remove and delete the tag.
Thoughts?

Comment: in case if the tag survives the review, here are two more questions that look worth having it: [What software programming languages were used by the Soviet Union's space program?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/145669/31260) and [What was the historical impact of Ariane 5's Flight 501?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/149888/31260)

Comment: [tag:spaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaace]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd vote for removing the tag. It doesn't add anything to any of the questions it's currently on and doesn't really work as the only tag on a question.

Comment: I've removed the tag from the four posts.  Does anything else need to be done to kill off the tag?  Anything else == within my reputation to do?

Comment: @GlenH7 - That'll be enough to stop it being suggested. If it keeps coming back we'll have to look at blacklisting it, but that's the last resort.

Answer (score 6):

How about we create a [space-technology] tag, and replace [space] with it? Our space technology questions are awesome, and I'd like to have an easy way of finding them.

Comment: For 3 of the 4 that were tagged with space that would make sense.  It should be fairly easy to hunt those posts down again and find others that should have been tagged that way if they had only known.

Comment: @GlenH7 Already done it for some of the questions...

Comment: Thought you would be interested to see the tag in use.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/159938/53019

Answer (score 1):

I'd vote for removing the tag because it's difficult to disambiguate the word 'space' when it exists within a tag that is among other "programming" tags.